# Eliminar una fila de una tabla con jquery

Tags: jquery

Buen dia,

tengo la siguiente tabla creada dinamicamente con un boton de agregar (despues de leer el select y el input y otras cosas)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo hago con el siguiente codigo cada vez que doy click a agregar

```
$("#tabla_presentaciones_en_modal_crear_pedido").append("<tr><td class='codigo'>"+codigo_presentacion+
    "</td><td class='nombre'>"+nombre_presentacion+
    "</td><td class='cant_cajas'>"+cantidad_cajas+
    "</td><td class='peso_caja'>"+peso_caja+"</td><td><button onclick='eliminar_fila_presentacion(this)' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>Eliminar</button></td></tr>");
```

a cada td le coloqué una clase,

ya pudé recorrer todos los tr y de acuerdo al td que tiene el codigo de la presentacion (producto), validar ya está en la tabla o no, lo hice con este codigo

```
$('#tabla_presentaciones_en_modal_crear_pedido tr .codigo').each(function(){
    var codigo_iterado = $(this).html();
    
    console.log("codigo iterado:"+codigo_iterado);    
    if(codigo_iterado == codigo_presentacion)
    {
      Swal.fire('Presentacion ya escogida','','error');
      validacion = true;
      return;
    }    
  });
```

Ahora lo que quisiera es eliminar la fila al dar click al boton eliminar, le puse a cada uno onclick='eliminar_fila_presentacion(this)', tengo entendido que jQuery tiene selectores pero no he podido,

alguna idea?

Gracias!!

Comment: @masterguru Gracias, perfecto, no sabia lo de jerarquias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba de este modo:

```js
var codigo_presentacion = "1"
var nombre_presentacion = "nombre presentación"
var cantidad_cajas = "10"
var peso_caja = "100kg"
$("#tabla_presentaciones_en_modal_crear_pedido").append("<tr><td class='codigo'>" + codigo_presentacion +
  "</td><td class='nombre'>" + nombre_presentacion +
  "</td><td class='cant_cajas'>" + cantidad_cajas +
  "</td><td class='peso_caja'>" + peso_caja + "</td><td><button onclick='eliminar_fila_presentacion(this)' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>Eliminar</button></td></tr>");


function eliminar_fila_presentacion(obj) {
  $(obj).parent().parent().remove()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabla_presentaciones_en_modal_crear_pedido">

</table>
```

### Cambios realizados

- Hemos definido esta función:

```javascript
function eliminar_fila_presentacion(obj) {
  $(obj).parent().parent().remove()
}
```

donde:

- `obj` nos identifica al elemento pulsado, representado por `this` en la llamada del onclick, es decir, el botón
- `parent()` nos situa un nivel por encima de dicho elemento, es decir, en la definición de columna `td`
- `parent()` con otro parent seguimos subiendo hasta otro nivel por encima, es decir, ahora estamos en la definición de fila `tr`
- `remove()` nos elimina el elemento referenciado por las otras instrucciones, es decir, el `tr` que contiene la definición de columna `td` que contiene al botón pulsado, eliminado toda la fila y el resto de columnas que contenga.